# Dynamic Linq : is it stable?

Tags: .net, linq, dynamic, status, dynamic-linq

[Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) is provided as a sample for VS2008, not as a "real" project (no official site, no support, no issue tracking, no new releases...).

So I was wondering, how reliable is it ? Is it suitable for production use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are a $2.5B solar manufacturing company, and we are using it for mission critical manufacturing applications. It is reliable, fast and suitable for production use.